# &amp; in XML does not get replaced by &

Tags: xml, powershell, msbuild, escaping

I'm currently tweaking my msbuild file for continuous integration. To be more specific, I try to call powershell to do task on remote server within msbuild file, underthe guidance from [Microsoft official help](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/running-windows-powershell-scripts-from-msbuild-project-files). Everything is great except the "&amp;" in the msbuild file does not get replaced by "&". For example,

```
<Exec Command="powershell.exe -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted 
                 -command &quot;&amp; invoke-command 
                          -Computername &apos;RemoteServer&apos;
                          -scriptblock {...}
                          &quot;"/>
```

When the msbuild script contains above executes, the command is translated as

```
powershell.exe -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted 
             -command "&amp; invoke-command 
                      -Computername 'RemoteServer'
                      -scriptblock {...}
                      "
```

As you can see, "&quot;" and "&apos;" are successfully translated whereas "&amp;" is not.

Any clue is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Even though the execution of the msbuild script would complain about the command and display "&amp;" in the message. But it is not the root of the issue.

The root is msbuild script does not like the single powershell command to spread multiple lines.

```
<Exec Command="powershell.exe -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command &quot;&amp; invoke-command -Computername &apos;RemoteServer&apos; -scriptblock {...}  &quot;"/>
```

Once I changed it like above. It works as expected.